# Direct3D MDI Project: MFC or .NET?

Tags: mfc, direct3d

I'm looking at a new project where both Native and Managed approaches sound like a good idea. This is a Windows desktop application which should support an MDI interface. The client area will make extensive use of Direct3D. The developers on the project are equally skilled on C#, C++/CLI and MFC.

MFC Advantages:

- Doc/View Architecture
- Most Direct3D online resources still use C++

Managed Code Advantages:

- The .NET Framework
- C#

What more can I add to the lists above? Don't flame this. Two lists. Just add to them.

Note: I have very good reasons (to do with the IDE and debugging) not to use mixed mode. So count that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use both?

You can write the UI (forms) using C#/VB.NET and render the window using C++.

Basically all you need to do is pass the HWND (Window Handle) from the C# to the C++ and initialize the C++ using that value.

You can see an example on my blog: [How-to Render managed (.NET) form using native DirectX](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dhelper/archive/2008/11/24/how-to-render-managed-net-form-using-native-directx.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly add to either list, but the current "recommended" way to do 3D with .NET is using XNA - Managed DirectX is being deprecated.

Edit: Of course, WPF 3D is also an option! Forgot about that  :}

Comment: Nah. Pointers as to why MDX is being deprecated in favor of XNA?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry... it's fallen into the realms of "assumed knowledge"  :}